# Tramp fails for filename containing colon

Tags: emacs, tramp

Tramp mode of emacs fails to get remote file when the filename contains a colon. (Works for other filenames on remote server.)  Cannot see anything about colons in
manual, only 'A remote file name containing a host name, which is the same string as a method name, is not allowed', which is not the case here.  Have tried escaping colon without success.  Does anyone have a solution?

FYI command used was:

`emacs /ssh:servername.net/~/TRAILS/AMoleraSP:_Beach_Trail.gpx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote file name syntax is wrong, you miss the colon after the host name. And there is a superfluous slash. Try

```
emacs /ssh:servername.net:~/TRAILS/AMoleraSP:_Beach_Trail.gpx
```

Comment: Embarrassed. Looking back at history, somehow colon for successful case got replaced by slash when changing filenames and I focused on colon in new name.